# Duplicates with open bounties

Tags: discussion

I'm curious - should anything be done on questions about questions with active bounties that are duplicates? I'm thinking specifically of [Optimal value for Nginx worker_connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/787919/optimal-value-for-nginx-worker-connections) as a dupe of our canonical capacity planning question, but I'm wondering what as a community we should do in the more general case.

Comment: I agree with Sven as a bounty is not a excuse to treat a question differently. Personally in that case I'm not sure I would had v-t-c for dupe. As it's not my server is X, what value to put there, but I would had surely v-t-c as "Questions without a clear problem statement ". In all cases it would had finished as Sven's told (flag & bounty reimbursement) I think for any bad questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My view: A bounty should not be an excuse to treat a question differently. If necessary, mods can remove the bounty (including a reimbursement of the rep spent), so when in doubt, flag for mod attention.

(Before I do this with your example, I'll wait for differing opinions and votes on those. )

Answer (score 9):

I'm in the "bounties make no difference" camp.  Annoyingly, though, the question asks two *completely* separate questions, though, and while the first is a straight-up capacity planning dupe, the second... is actually valid.  There may be a dupe somewhere out there, but it isn't part of the capacity planning question.

Frankly, for multi-part questions like that, I'm in favour of v-t-c "Too Broad" with a comment saying "one question per question, please: edit your question to include only one actual question, and post a new question for the other(s)" -- and then hammer the resulting parts into the ground if required.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question with the bounty should be prefered. Otherwise people ask the bounty question again, then wait for an answer and use it to answer the bounty question to get the points.